# CSV to MSSQL using pymssql

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pymssql

the motive is to continuously look for new records in my CSV and insert the records to the mssql using pymssql library.
The CSV initially has 244 rows and I'm trying to insert 1 value and wants to dynamically insert the new row only when the script is ran with the scheduler.
I have the script which runs every 15 seconds to insert the values, but post inserting the values the first time, the second time the script throws 'Cannot insert duplicate key in object' as I have my first column `DateID` which is set a PK and terminates the statement from the first record itself, therefore doesn't insert the new row.

How do I encounter this.

Code:

```
def trial():
    try: 
        for row in df.itertuples():
         
            datevalue = datetime.datetime.strptime(row.OrderDate, format)

            query= "INSERT INTO data (OrderDate, Region, City, Category) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            cursor.execute(query, (datevalue, row.Region,row.City,row.Category))
        print('"Values inserted')
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Handle error", e)
        pass
        

schedule.every(15).seconds.do(trial)
```

Library used: pymssql
SQL: MSSQL server 2019

Comment: Where is `DateID` in your query?

Comment: @Parfait actually I'm getting an error from the exception while running executemany

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid duplicate values, consider adjusting query to use `EXCEPT` clause (part of `UNION` and `INTERSECT` set operator family) against actual data. Also, consider using `executemany` by passing a nested list of all row/column data with `DataFrame.to_numpy().tolist()`.

By the way if `OrderDate` column is a `datetime` type in data frame and database table, you do not need to re-format to string value.

```py
def trial():
    try: 
        query= (
            "INSERT INTO data (OrderDate, Region, City, Category) "
            "SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s "
            "EXCEPT "
            "SELECT OrderDate, Region, City, Category "
            "FROM data"
        )

        vals = df[["OrderDate", "Region", "City", "Category"]].to_numpy()
        vals = tuple(map(tuple, vals))
        cur.executemany(query, vals)

        print('Values inserted')
        conn.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Handle error", e)

    finally:
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
```

For a faster, bulk insert, consider using a staging, temp table:

```py
# CREATE EMPTY TEMP TABLE 
query = "SELECT TOP 0 OrderDate, Region, City, Category INTO #pydata FROM data"
cur.execute(query)

# INSERT INTO TEMP TABLE
query= (
    "INSERT INTO #pydata (OrderDate, Region, City, Category) "
    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) "
)
vals = df[["OrderDate", "Region", "City", "Category"]].to_numpy()
vals = tuple(map(tuple, vals))
cur.execute("BEGIN TRAN")
cur.executemany(query, vals)

# MIGRATE TO FINAL TABLE
query= (
    "INSERT INTO data (OrderDate, Region, City, Category) "
    "SELECT OrderDate, Region, City, Category "
    "FROM #pydata "
    "EXCEPT "
    "SELECT OrderDate, Region, City, Category "
    "FROM data"
)
cur.execute(query)
conn.commit()
print("Values inserted")
```

Comment: Thank you for the coment, I ran your solution but I'm getting 'params' arg (<class 'list'>) can be only a tuple or a dictionary error from the except handle.

Comment: See update converting data frame to tuple of tuples instead of lists of lists.

Comment: I can run the solution now, it inserts the value avoiding duplicate, but after the first run it throws: 'Cannot commit transaction: (3902, b'The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n')'

Actually I have put it within scheduler. So when it reruns it throws it.

Comment: Try adding `cur.execute("BEGIN TRAN")` just before `executemany`.

Comment: Sure @Parfait let me try this. I have been trying your solution, In my csv I have around 100,000 rows, after the insertion, when it goes for the next iteration, it takes lot of time again to insert the new row, I guess it is again starting from the 1st row right ? Does it take this much time to check each row as been already inserted to avoid the duplicate ?

Comment: So to get the 100,001'th row to be ingested, it again goes through from the 1st row right. How to speed up the process ?

Comment: See extended answer using a staging, temp table which will check duplicates in a _single_ query rather than iteratively for each row.

Comment: ok I'll try this out once. I was trying with `BULK INSERT` but I couldn't get that query fit into the above scenario. Even the first iteration to insert 100,000 rows is taking time, even more executemany and also I have put fast_executemany = True, Is this behaviour expected ? Also when I use pyodbc with executemany, the sql server hangs or can't use select query, Plus if I interrupt the code in between, the insertion stops in mid but the sql server doesn't have the data which it ws inserting for that much time. With pymssql, even if I interrupt the code in midway, it has inserted data so far